# How can I run sudo hidd --search without a password?

Tags: sudo

If I run `hidd --search` it says `HID create error 13 (Permission denied)`

If I run as sudo it connects fine.

I want this script to run on login.  I saw [how to edit sudoers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password), but will it create a security weakness if I add 
`%MYNAME ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/hidd`

Is there a group I can add myself to that means I can run this command without sudo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run it without a password by editing the /etc/sudoers file as you mentioned.  One step further would be to append `alias hidd='sudo hidd'` to your  `~/.bashrc` file.

I don't know of any other way besides sudo.

If it needs root to run, I do believe groups won't help you.  However, if it has a daemon running as root [Like `wicd`], groups might help you out, but I would tend to doubt it.