# run script as root without password

Tags: mount, sudo

I want to run a script without prompt for password.
I edited /etc/sudoers file and I wrote several lines behind last one. This is my file:

```
#
Defaults    env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

jose ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -h now
jose ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -r now
jose ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/jose/sync.sh
```

The script code (it works fine with password) is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 
#Filename: sync.sh

echo "Empezando sincronizar....."

ping -c 1 -t 1 172.18.2.100 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null # ping and discard output

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then # check the exit code
echo "${ip} is up" # display the output
sudo mount -t smbfs //172.18.2.100/Downloads /home/jose/pc1
rsync -r -u -verbose /home/jose/pc1/movies/ /home/jose/Movies/
rsync -r -u -verbose /home/jose/pc1/series/ /home/jose/TV?Shows/
sudo umount /home/jose/pc1

# you could send this to a log file by using the >>pinglog.txt redirect
else
echo "${ip} is down"
fi

echo "Fin sincronizacion"
```

I can shutdown and reboot without type password but when I try to run the last line, the script prompt for password. I replace the script path for "ALL" and I can run root comands without password but I can't run the mount / umount command and the script.

User belongs....

jose : jose adm dialout cdrom floppy audio video plugdev users lpadmin sambashare admin

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, this appears to be abandoned. Could you please post the output requested (`whereis mount`)? I've voted this for closure, but if you're still working through this issue it can be reopened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow execution without using the sudo?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72267/how-to-allow-execution-without-using-the-sudo)

Answer (score 3):

### The fix

1. In `/etc/sudoers` make sure the line is still there says:

   ```
   jose ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/jose/sync.sh
   ```

   Do NOT delete that line!
2. **Optional**: In your script, remove the `sudo`s in front of every command using for exapmle:

   ```
   sed -i 's/^\(\s*\)sudo\s*/\1/g' /home/jose/sync.sh
   ```

   This is not necessary but proofs a point. You can leave the files as it is, if you want to be able to execute it as regular user, without `sudo /home/jose/sync.sh`, and then be asked for a password.
3. Run your script with:

   ```
   sudo /home/jose/sync.sh
   ```

   `sudo` will **not prompt you for a password**. It is important to have the sudo in front of your call to the script.

Also for **security reasons** run the following commands on your script:

```
sudo chown root:root /home/jose/sync.sh
sudo chmod o-rwx /home/jose/sync.sh
```

This way no one can edit your script without the root password. This important because else everyone that sits on your computer as a free and password-less method to execute commands as root.

### The problem

The problem with the way you did it is, that you give permissions to run the script with root privileges but don't actually run it as root using `sudo`.

The only thing you run as root are the two commands that have "sudo" in front of them (which are of course `umount /home/jose/pc1` and `mount -t smbfs //172.18.2.100/Downloads /home/jose/pc1`). But those two mount commands do NOT have root permissions (and should NOT despite [pl1nk](https://askubuntu.com/users/48864/pl1nk) describing how you'd give them root permission in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/150250/17789)), as they are not listed in `/etc/sudoers` to have `NOPASSWD` fot the user `jose`.

Answer (score 2):

In /etc/sudoers (**please use `visudo` to edit**) add:

```
jose ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
jose ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/umount
```

Comment: I put this lines but it doesn't work, I tried with /bin/mount  too,

Comment: @jibtga - Run `whereis mount`

Comment: Also putting these lines into `/etc/sudoers` is a very bad id since you allow a user to mount/unmount basically everything. That enables everyone with access to do anything with your computer.