# How to make 'sudo' grab the password from a file?

Tags: 12.04, sudo

I want to run a command that requires the sudo password say:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Isn't this supposed to work (I have stored the password in a normal text file `passwd.txt`):

```
sudo apt-get update <~/passwd.txt
```

This is my logic for for why it SHOULD work: when the password is required, the user is asked to input the password from the keyboard. But redirecting the `stdin` to read from the `passwd.txt` file should work.

Shouldn't it?

Comment: Read [sudo with password in one command line?](http://superuser.com/q/67765).

Comment: You would noramlly use `expect` tcl script to automate such things.

Comment: If you need to ask this, you're probably doing something wrong. Could you share what you're trying to accomplish in the first place? One should never have to use hacks like this. It's an indication that there should be a better solution.

Comment: @gertvdijk
I am not an expert of ubuntu but I m learning. I gave this to myself as an exercise: "Execute a command in a Bash Script that requires sudo privilege using only the knowledge that I currently possess. Without using Google."
I came up with the above answer and I thought tht it should work.
I found better, safer solutions on AskUbuntu later.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`sudo` doesn't read password from `stdin` by default. From `sudo` manpage:

```
-S  The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device.
    The password must be followed by a newline character.
```

So you should run:

```
sudo -S apt-get update <~/passwd.txt
```

---

Keep in mind that storing passwords in files is not a good practice. You should read:

- [How to allow execution without using sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/q/72267/65926)
- [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/159007/65926)
- [How to run an application using sudo without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/39281/65926)

Comment: Understood! Short n sweet answer!

Comment: to make it self-documenting I would just use `sudo --stdin apt-get update`