# Microsoft Designer mouse on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 15.10

I have recently upgraded my system to the Ubuntu 15.10 version and somehow my mouse pointer seems to not work until I restart my drivers. Is there a possible way to have a permanent solution and not restart it everytime. I have tried the solutions at [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working). But this does not work.

Also, I tried to connect my system to the Microsoft Designer mouse, but the mouse doesn't show up in the bluetooth list what-so-ever and I have the Atheros 3011 driver and hence this [Microsoft Designer Mouse (Bluetooth 4.0) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646433/microsoft-designer-mouse-bluetooth-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) does not work. Please help me work around this.

Comment: run the command as a startup application?

Comment: @Mateo doesn't restarting the driver require sudo?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72267/how-to-allow-execution-without-using-the-sudo , http://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password