# Software that listens on a port, and shuts down Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, tomcat7

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (installed using Wubi) on a Dell Dimention 3000 (**not** a server). I want to install some software that will listen on a certain port, and shut down the system upon either a connection, or a command. I have tried using SSH, but I want something faster. Something similar to Tomcat's shutdown port is what I am looking for. Another option is possibly a tomcat webapp (I run tomcat on that server), that on load will shut down my computer. However, I definitely prefer another software to handle that task. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much,
vikarjramun

Comment: Don't think there is anything faster then ssh.

Comment: So you just want something which will listen on the port and when there is activity, shutdown the system?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda exactly

Comment: @vikarjramun: Is the machine you want to shutdown CLI-only or does it have a GUI?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I do have a GUI. I **mildly** prefer using a CLI, but a GUI is fine with me

Comment: @vikarjramun: Well, the only answer I can give at the moment is one with a GUI, so unless you find another way, that might have to do for the moment. At least until someone can think of a better CLI solution.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Your GUI solution is perfectly fine! I definitely prefer that over creating my own TCP server

Comment: @vikarjramun: Well, if you feel my answer solved you problem, please click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer solved my problem](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! **;-)**

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, but if it works, I will most definitely select your answer!

Comment: @vikarjramun: Ok, let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Specto` sounds like what you want, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install specto
```

Then launch it with `specto` or search for it in the dash. To set it to listen on a port and then shutdown the machine when there is activity do:

1. Click the `Add` button and then go `System > Port`.

[image: Add Port Watch]

2. Enter the name of the watch, the refresh interval and the port number in the first tab.

[image: General Watch Preferences]

3. Go to the `Advanced options` tab and set it to run `sudo poweroff` when there is activity on that port.

[image: Run command on activity]

4. In order for it to work you will need to add `specto` to your startup items and run it with `sudo` too.

Comment: I am installing specto now, how do I add it to startup items?

Comment: @vikarjramun: Open `Startup Applications` (`gnome-session-properties`) and add the command `sudo specto` as a startup item. You'll probably want to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/72272/364819) answer too so that it doesn't prompt you for your `sudo` password each time. If you would prefer it to prompt you for your `sudo` password each time then please let me know and I will advise you on that (because then using `sudo` wouldn't be the right thing to do if you wanted it to actually manage to prompt you).

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search for "perl tcp server example" will show your several (405,000) examples of how to write a simple client (to send a "shutdown" message to port 30102 on the server) and a simple TCP/IP server to listen for the connection on port 30102, do the desired identification/authentication/authorization dance, then (if the server is started as `root`) shutdown the system.

Comment: Could I possibly write this in Java? I am not familiar with perl.

Comment: I have no clue as to your Java skills. The perl examples are pretty much cut-and-paste. Or, you could google "Java tcp server example".

Comment: none of the perl examples I saw could shutdown the system

Comment: The perl examples probably have a dummy action (to demonstrate their functionality). Surely one could replace this action with a call to `/sbin/shutdown`

Comment: do you know how to do this using perl?

Comment: I did it with Perl many years ago, it was very simple then, but I've been programming since 1967