# Run a command that requires sudo after a time has passed

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo

I usually do

```
sleep 4h; command
```

to execute a command after 4h. However, if that command requires `sudo`, it'll not work.

Is it possible to give `sudo` permission at the moment I'm running the `sleep` command?

Comment: something like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391796/pipe-password-to-sudo-and-other-data-to-sudoed-command

Comment: In that particular case I think you can just use the `shutdown`. command with sudo and the appropriate arguments to schedule sleep at a specific time.

Comment: Related:  [Pre-authorize sudo? (So it can be run later)](https://superuser.com/q/640491/354511) and [sudo in non-interactive script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190571/80216).

Comment: What is the task you need to do, and why the exact 4 hour sleep?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `sudo` to start a root shell where you run the commands:

```
sudo bash -c 'sleep 4h; command'
```

Every command running in the root shell runs with root permissions, which for `sleep` doesn’t hurt. If you need to run a command with user permissions in it, use `sudo -u USERNAME COMMAND`, e.g.:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'sleep 4h; sudo -u dessert whoami; whoami'
dessert  # whoami run as user dessert
root     # whoami run as root
```

---

Another approach would be to use `sudo visudo` to allow the command’s execution without root access, see:
[How to allow execution without prompting for password using sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/q/72267/507051)
Note that depending on the command this may create a security flaw.

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you only want to run the process once (not, e.g. every 4 hours) then you can use `atd`

1. Ensure that atd is running (in ubuntu that is `/etc/init.d/atd status` or better still `systemctl status atd`)
2. At a terminal as root run your command as follows:

   ```
   # at now + 4 hours
   warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
   at> command
   at> CTRL-D
   ```
3. If you want to run it every 4 hours you could also use cron (as root) with the following config in your crontab

   ```
   0 */4 * * * sh -c $'/path/to/command'
   ```

Comment: Yes, `at` is the right tool for this job, because it also takes care of I/O redirection, doesn't block a shell window, and works even when the user has logged out or the machine has been rebooted since.

Comment: @SimonRichter: `sudo bash -c 'sleep 4h && command' &` to put sudo in the background is an easier way to not block a shell window / tab.  If you *want* the output to pop up asynchronously as a reminder that it happened, that's easier.  It doesn't work across reboots, but depending on your `nohup` settings it might stay running after exiting / logging out from a shell.

Comment: Note that `at` runs the command as soon as it’s able to when the system is suspended at the specified time, see [here on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/411022/246819) – depending on the command(s) to run this may not be what you want.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can also use systemctl to check the service status instead of directly calling that init.d script. While both seemingly have the same result, I think the modern way of interacting with systemd services should be preferred: `systemctl status atd`

Answer (score 15):

One way is to run via a shellscript with `sudo` permissions (and give the password, when you start the shellscript), if the shellscript is in the current directory,

```
sudo ./delayer 4h
```

where `delayer` can be a shellscript with the content

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep "$1"
command
```

Make it executable with

```
chmod +x delayer
```

and copy or move it to a directory in `PATH` if you wish.

---

If you want a more flexible shellscript, where you can select the command [line] to delay by entering parameter(s), you can try

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ] || [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]
then
 echo "Delay start of command, that needs 'sudo'
Usage:    sudo $0 <delay> <command line>
Example:  sudo $0 4h parted -ls"
 exit
fi

sleep "$1"
shift
"$@"
```

Demo example (short delay, 5s, for demo purpose),

```
$ ./delayer
Delay start of command, that needs 'sudo'
Usage:    sudo ./delayer <delay> <command line>
Example:  sudo ./delayer 4h parted -ls

$ sudo ./delayer 5s parted /dev/sdc p
[sudo] password for sudodus: 
Model: Kanguru SS3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 15,9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 2      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB               primary  bios_grub
 3      2097kB  258MB   256MB   fat32        primary  boot, esp
 4      258MB   2274MB  2016MB               primary
 5      2274MB  12,5GB  10,2GB  ext2         primary
 1      12,5GB  15,9GB  3394MB  ntfs         primary  msftdata
```

Comment: Well, if it's `/bin/sh` syntax it will be fine. But if you intend on using bash-specific features, then shebang is necessary. Me and steeldriver had discussion about that somewhere. Aaand Videonauth deleted his comment before I could respond properly. Oh well

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, You are right. So in this case the shebang is there to make the shellscript robust in case of added features where the syntax may differ.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Well it was just a suggestion so I thought leaving the comment there was not necessary and would only add to clutter. Feel free to hit me up in chat and point out your view :)

Comment: Don't do this when `$HOME` or `$USER` variable is referenced in the script or any script/program that's sourced by the script.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to start sudo interactive session with `sudo -s` (does not change directory) or `sudo -i` (changes current directory to root home directory) and then enter your commands (without sudo)