# Can I run sudo without entering a password?

Tags: password, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run an application using sudo without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password)

I like Ubuntu, but I hate entering a password every time when I run a command with sudo. Can I avoid it?