# Can I automate updating/upgrading with sudo in this way?

Tags: command-line, apt, password, sudo

Please consider this code:

```
alias fast='echo "password" | sudo -S apt-get update && sudo -S apt-get upgrade'
```

I have not yet had a problem using it but is it possible that if the first step, `apt-get update` takes a very long time, the password would lapse by the time the `apt-get upgrade` commands finally runs?

Comment: Have you changed the hostname?

Comment: No? I've never looked into changing the hostname and I have no idea whether it's a good or bad thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but is it possible that if the first step, `apt-get update` takes a very long time, the password would lapse by the time the `apt-get upgrade` commands finally runs?

The answer is yes, `sudo` could time out and ask you for the password again.

- Another method which is still insecure (but at least it does not require you writing a password to file) is described at [How to run an application using sudo without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/39281/6969)
- If you want to proceed with an approach where you write your password down in cleartext, consider chaining the command together and use `sh` to execute it:

  ```
  echo password | sudo sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade"
  ```

  In this way, `sudo` requires you to enter the password only once, and `sh` is executed as root. Then any programs run by `sh` are automatically running as root.
- Finally, you can pass the password twice to the separate programs:

  ```
  echo password | sudo apt-get update && echo password | sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the timeout for sudo is 15 minutes.

You can change that

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the timeout to this line

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

So for 20 minutes

```
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=20
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout

Comment: Given it is 15 min and assuming `apt-get update` takes longer, would `apt-get upgrade` require re-entering the password with reference to the alias in the question?

Comment: I should have edited the question title rather than answering it ;)

Comment: Yes, my question was poorly framed given what I really wanted to know.

Comment: Such is life - not important - the information is there now and if someone happens across it and it helps them then that is good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile now so can't write a detailed answer. However, there's another possibility that might be a suitable compromise.

You can configure sudo to not ask for a password for the apt-get command. You set this using the visudo command. Since I don't have access to my Linux boxes now, I can't tell you how to do it, but you can try reading the man pages for sudoers, visudo, and anything referenced by those pages.

**WARNING:** Doing this could potentially allow anyone to run any apt-get command. You will have to judge whether the convenience of this method outweighs the additional security risk.