# How to run a file with sudo without a password?

Tags: files, password, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run an application using sudo without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password)

I've made a script that preforms various system tasks, that I run regularly, but I have to use sudo to run the script, despite the fact that I own it because it runs root privileged commands. How can I add make sudo let me run this one file without having to enter my password every time I run it?

I know that there are questions regarding running commands without a password, but I wasn't able to find one on running a file without a password.

I am aware of the security risks, but I'm at home on a computer that I trust.

I added `john ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/john/.script/hibernate.sh` to my `/etc/sudoers` but when running the command `sudo sh /home/john/.script/hibernate.sh` it still prompts me for my password...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `visudo` for a safe editing environment to edit the sudoers file. This script is a wrapper around `vi` that also does syntax checking when you save the file and won't let you overwrite a valid sudoers file with an invalid one.

Add a line like this:

```
username ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script
```

The "ALL=" bears some elaboration, it specifies that the permission is granted when the user in question is logged in from any location, locally (console or terminal) or remotely (ssh, etc).

Comment: For whatever reason, this method doesn't work. My username is john, and the file resides in ".script" which is inside my home. So i entered "john ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/john/.script/hibernate.sh" where hibernate.sh is the name of the script. After running "sudo sh /home/john/.script/hibernate.sh" it still asks for my password...

Comment: You need to make your .sh script executable and then just do "sudo /home/john/.script/hibernate.sh". The way you're trying to run it, john would need sudo permission to /bin/sh

Comment: the file is already executable, or at least is showed as such in nautilus > properties.

Comment: I just used chmod +rwx, and it still won't work...

Comment: the +x is step one. now change your command from "sh script" to "script"

Answer (score 3):

For completeness sake, you can achieve a similar effect by setting [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit in the file's permissions.

A slightly tricky part is that for security reasons `setuid` bit on scripts is ignored by the kernel, so you'll need to compile a small wrapper program in C and use it to invoke your script. Save this as `runscript.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   setuid( 0 );
   system( "/path/to/script.sh" );

   return 0;
}
```

then compile it with

```
gcc runscript.c -o runscript
```

and set `setuid` bit on the executable:

```
sudo chown root:root runscript
sudo chmod 4755 runscript
```

It is also important to make sure your script is only writable by root, since everyone who can modify the script will be able to execute arbitrary programs:

```
sudo chown root:root /path/to/script.sh
sudo chmod 0711 /path/to/script.sh
```

Here's an article I've got the wrapper program code from: [setuid on shell scripts](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html).

Security-wise, both approaches - the one with `sudo` and the one with `setuid` - are pretty bad, but probably will be ok on a home machine. The difference is that *every* user in the system will be able to run a `setuid` command, even without being in the `sudoers` file. Also, obviously, you won't need to prefix the command with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

You need the "NOPASSWD" tag.

Use visudo and set something like this at the end of the file:

username ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/echo

Replace username with your username, and /bin/echo with the command you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the full path to the program you're running to the sudoers file, not the script. I'm assuming it's pm-hibernate, so:

```
john ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-hibernate
```