# Execute sudo command (openvt) with global shortcut

Tags: scripts, gnome-screensaver

My goal here is to run the [`cmatrix`](http://www.asty.org/cmatrix/) script and lock the desktop simultaneously, so that cmatrix will be shown as a screensaver until I come back and unlock the computer.

My script looks like this:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l & sudo openvt -ws cmatrix
```

Now I wanted to make the script be able to run without the need to input the sudo password everytime, so I changed the sudoers file ([like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/201551/355003)). It is working if I run it in the terminal, so far so good.

Then I added it to the `PATH`, because I wanted to bind it to the global shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+L`, but it doesn't work if I invoke it via the shortcut. The desktop just flashes for a split second, like it wanted to show `cmatrix`, but then it goes straight to the unlock screen.

I figured out that the part with `openvt` isn't working like it should, even if it is the only thing in the script.

Any ideas how to accomplish what I want?

---

EDIT: In the split second when the desktop flashes, I managed to read this on the screen:

```
Error opening terminal: unknown
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually now I found the solution myself - the problem and the solution are the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826241/running-nano-in-docker-container). I just had to add this line into my script:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look at this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91541/why-is-path-reset-in-a-sudo-command
Your PATH is being reset when you issue a sudo command, so evil hacker could not change and point it to malicious `cmatrix` script. So modify your secure path or append exact location of your `cmatrix` program to the sudo command.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, since the script works even if I run `sudo su` before it, so everything is on the PATH of the root user.

Comment: @lmazgon: Script works after `sudo su` because you gain root privileges with `su` and then run it as 'regular' command from root account. `sudo` won't let you run commands located outside 'secure' path without providing full path to them. E.g. if you put your script on `/unsecure/path/script` and then do `export PATH=/unsecure/path; sudo script` it won't run, but `sudo /unsecure/path/script` will.

Comment: I get your point. Still, everything I am executing is on a secure path, i.e. `/usr/bin`  or `/bin`. Anyway, I found the solution, thanks for your input!

Comment: @lmazgon: If you've found the solution then share it, so you can help others with similar problems.

Comment: It is right above yours, I just can't accept the answer yet, because it is my own. I'll do it tomorrow ;)