# Auto dimming laptop keyboard backlit when idle

Tags: command-line, scripts, keyboard, power-management, brightness

On Windows 10, my laptop's keyboard backlit automatically turned off after a minute or so of inactivity. As soon as any activity occurred, they turned back on.

On ubuntu, if I run the following

```
echo <0-3> | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

That works for dimming / increasing the brightness (0 being turned off, 3 being brightest).

Is there a way to have the above automatically get executed whenever the system's been idle for 1 minute, as well as re-run it when it comes back from being idle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What you need to do

1. Install `xprintidle`, to keep track of the current idle time (defined by lack of keyboard- and mouse events).
2. Create a small background script (further below); copy the script into an empty file and save it as `dim_keyboard.sh`. ***Make the script executable*** and copy it to a location where unauthorized users cannot alter the script (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`).
3. Add the script to the `sudoers` file, since you run the command with `sudo`: Add the line:

   ```
   <username> ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script
   ```

   (where `<username>` is your username) to the file, as explained e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/201551/72216).

---

**N.B.** In the `sudoers` file, for security reasons always use the **full path** to the script, also if it is in `$PATH`. The reason is that else it would be easy to place a similarly named script in `~/bin`, which could run with `sudo` privileges, possibly with malicious code.

---

4. Test- run the script with the idle time (in seconds) as an argument:

   ```
   sudo /path/to/script.sh 60
   ```

   To dim the backlight after a minute
5. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. add the command:

   ```
   sudo /path/to/script.sh 60
   ```

#### The script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

let "div = 1000"
let "limit = $1"
dimmed=false
cmd=/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness

while true
do
  sleep 2
  let "idle = $(xprintidle)"
  if [ $(($idle / $div)) -gt $limit ] && [ $dimmed == false ]; then
    echo 0 | tee $cmd 
    dimmed=true
  elif [ $(($idle / $div)) -le $limit ] && [ $dimmed == true ]; then
    echo 3 | tee $cmd 
    dimmed=false
  fi
done
```

Comment: /usr/local/bin/dim_keyboard.sh: line 11: let: idle = : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "= ")
/usr/local/bin/dim_keyboard.sh: line 12: / 1000: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ 1000")

Comment: @ClickUpvote It works on my system, but the "$(xprintidle)" might be interpreted as a string. could you replace the line by `let "idle = $(xprintidle)"`?

Comment: Sorry, I was testing before adding the file to sudoers (even though I was doing `sudo dim_keyboard.sh`.) After adding to sudoers, it works fantastically :) Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, on reboot, it asks for password when run, even though I've added `username ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/dim_keyboard.sh` as the last line of sudoers via `sudo visudo`.

Comment: @ClickUpvote Oh crap! I totally forgot to mention, the script is fine, but the startup command is wrong: should be with `sudo`. will edit.

Comment: Also, `username ALL` should be `clickupvote ALL`, i.e username should be replaced by the actual username, right?

Answer (score 0):

To continue the https://askubuntu.com/a/762994/954857 answer. Do add the following

`savedState=$(cat /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness)`

Use this line to save the older state and reuse so the brightness will always be the same