# Included username and password in sudo -i command

Tags: server, bash

I want to do `sudo -i` within a bash script but also want to pass in the *sudo* username and password at the same time. Is that possible?

i.e. something like:

```
echo PASSWORD | sudo -k -S -i -u USERNAME
```

Comment: There are security issues with that method. An intruder will be able to see the root password in clear text, when reading the shellscript. There are other ways to make it possible to run one or a few tasks without password, that should be less risky than entering the password like that. See the answers at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201544/how-to-run-a-file-with-sudo-without-a-password).