# Run root script or command as root in startup application in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, command-line, 14.04, network-manager, startup

I have a wireless adapter that used to work in ubuntu 13.10 (dwa 171) after installing drivers for it. Now it won't work the same way anymore since I upgraded to ubuntu 14.04.

I've found the only way to make it work properly is to run the command `sudo service network-manager restart` I already tried putting this command in rc.local, rc2.local and rc3.local with no real luck. I want this command to run automatically right after login in with startup application program. Please tell me how to.

Comment: it doesn't work if u put on startup program list?

Comment: sudo is not expected or required in rc.local.

Comment: I didn't put sudo in rc.local and no it doesn't work on startup program list because it has sudo I think

Comment: to run a command as root after login, this is an option: http://askubuntu.com/a/486304/72216

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi everyone thanks for trying to answer my question. I have found a permanent fix for my network adapter that the newer release of ubuntu broke. My solution involved getting this ppa: `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mathieu-tl/nm/ubuntu saucy main` it has Ubuntu's 13.10 network manager package and wpasupplicant package. I went to synaptic and downgraded only the wpasupplicant package. I never have to run the command `sudo service network-manager restart` again.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer, cause it doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: It does answer the question because my initial problem was that my network adapter stopped working after upgrading to a newer release of ubuntu. Now it's fixed thanks to this. I advise you to read the description.

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo` command expects you to enter your password via a command prompt. Use `gksudo` instead, and you will be shown a GUI prompt to type your password in.

So the command to add to your startup applications would be:

```
gksu service network-manager restart
```

You might also want to delay that command from running right away, to give your desktop a chance to load:

```
sleep 15s; gksu service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this command run seamlessly without any user interaction once it's set?