# Possible to run gksudo without a password require?

Tags: password, gksudo

So i have xampp installed on my desktop and since it can use alot of ram if it stays active for a long time i followed tutorial to put together some kind of python script to start and stop services easy.

So the script goes like this, i made shortcut on desktop and when i click it opens a window when i can start/stop services like apache, mysql, ftp.

So the script starts command is this

```
gksudo "/opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel"
```

but every time i click shortcut annoying notification pop up ask me for a password.

Is it possible to disable password ask for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gksudo` is a frontend to `sudo` (see `man gksudo`). So you have to make `sudo` to not ask for a password. To do this, see:

- [Execute sudo without Password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/147241/147044)

And also you could be interested by:

- [How to run an application using sudo without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/39281/147044)

Comment: Thank you your links are exactly what i needed to read on. Now i don't have annoying asking every time i want to start xampp but sudo still requires pass for other things.