# tcpdump permissions problem

Tags: 14.04, permissions, tcpdump

Am having trouble running tcpdump. I must run tcpdump with non-root user. 
Searched the web for my problem and figured out I should:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_admin=eip /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

That enabled me to run *tcpdump* with my user but then I got:

```
you don't have permission to capture on that device
```

on any device I tried capturing.

Also went a little brute-force and did:

```
sudo chmod +s /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

That didn't do it either.

Comment: Tcpdump requires root privileges,you’ll have to set specific Linux capabilities to the binary:

$ sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/sbin/tcpdump

Comment: Did that too but i keep getting:
`tcpdump: eth0: You don't have permission to capture on that device
(socket: Operation not permitted`

Comment: see here.http://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password

Comment: This is also problematic because don't want to change the source code which i'm running...
Also, what _DreamCoder_ suggested should work but strangely it don't.
Anyone have another offer?

Answer (score 49):

It's a little late, but I just had the same problem. You need to give `tcpdump` the permission and capability to allow **raw packet captures** and **network interface manipulation**.

Add a capture group and add yourself to it:

```
sudo groupadd pcap
sudo usermod -a -G pcap $USER
```

Next, change the group of `tcpdump` and set permissions:

```
sudo chgrp pcap /usr/sbin/tcpdump
sudo chmod 750 /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

Finally, use `setcap` to give `tcpdump` the necessary permissions:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

Be careful, that this will allow everybody from the group **pcap** to manipulate network interfaces and read raw packets!

Found it here: [Configure tcpdump to work as non-root](https://web.archive.org/web/20160403142820/http://peternixon.net/news/2012/01/28/configure-tcpdump-work-non-root-user-opensuse-using-file-system-capabilities/)

Comment: I was able to limit this a bit and just use `cap_net_raw,cap_setpcap=ep`.  The removal of the `i` was because my program didn't need to fork.  This is for a custom binary, so ymmv.

Comment: This also worked for `iftop` a program that shows network utilization by IP address / DNS name

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work. Similar to what was posted already. It has not been tested on ubuntu.

(use a group of which your user is a member)
chgrp wireshark /usr/sbin/tcpdump

setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/sbin/tcpdump

using  getcap /usr/sbin/tcpdump you should see
/usr/sbin/tcpdump = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip