# Executing tcpdump without sudo on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, permissions, sudo, tcpdump

I want to capture UDP packages sent by an FPGA with ~10 Gbit/s bandwidth. I found that `tcpdump` combined with a fast SSD is perfectly capable of receiving a continuous 10 Gbit/s stream and storing it on disk without loss.

When I run `sudo tcpdump`, everything works as expected.

However, I need to be able to run `tcpdump` without `sudo`. Without `sudo` I get this error:

```
tcpdump: enp4s0f0: You don't have permission to capture on that device
(socket: Operation not permitted)
```

Here is what I found and tried so far to enable `tcpdump` without `sudo`:

```
sudo su
groupadd pcap
usermod -a -G pcap $USER
chgrp pcap /usr/sbin/tcpdump
chmod 750 /usr/sbin/tcpdump
setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

Proposed solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530920/tcpdump-permissions-problem)

According to the various pages that list this solution, this should give my regular user account the possibility to run `tcpdump`, right?

However, when I switch to my regular user account and run `tcpdump`, I get this:

`bash: /sbin/tcpdump: Permission denied`

(note that this error message is different compared to the initial error message)

I've verified via `getent group pcap` that my account is part of the `pcap` group. I've also verified that `/sbin/tcpdump` is owned by the group `pcap`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

After some experimenting, here is what finally worked for me:

`sudo visudo`

at the very END* of the sudoers file, enter this:

`your_username ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/tcpdump`

(replace `your_username` with your username, write the changes to disk close the editor)

open a new terminal and run `sudo tcpdump`. It no longer asks for a password.

*putting the new rule at the end avoids that it might be overwritten by other rules.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to leave a comment, but it seems that you have a mistake in the binary paths.

In the commands `chgrp` and `chmod` you use the path `/usr/sbin/tcpdump` (notice the `/usr` at the beginning). But in the error you seem to try to run the executable `/sbin/tcpdump` (without the `/usr` at the beginning.)

Try to run the command `which tcpdump` to find the path to the binary you are calling when running the `tcpdump` command and then use this path at the `chgrp` and `chmod` commands.

I just used the commands at your post with the correct path (i.e. the one given by `which tcpdump`) and it worked for my in Ubuntu 22.04 installation.

By the way, this is proper way to run `tcpdump`. You should run it as a user. Running it as root or with sudo is dangerous.

Comment: I think you have enough in here to warrant it being an attempt at an answer, rather than a comment.  However, I also *think* you're wrong here ;-).  `/sbin` is simply a symlink to `/usr/sbin` (see `ls -l /`) in Ubuntu (and most other distros), so either is correct (and the same) in this case.  In other words, this seems to be unlikely to be a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: Also, can you provide reference for the statement that, *"Running it as `root` or with `sudo` is dangerous"*?  Most all examples that I could find from *highly reputable* sources used `sudo`.  Thanks!

Comment: You are right both paths are the same directory. In this case, I do not know why it worked in my case and not in the OP's case.

Here is a short reference about why you should avoid running tcpdump (and in general any executable) as root if you can avoid it: https://www.securityartwork.es/2012/06/18/tcpdump-drop-privileges-2/

Recent versions of tcpdump seem to have some safeguards when the user runs them as root, since by default they use the `relinquish-privileges` flag.

Comment: Thanks - I'm glad it *did* work for you, of course ;-).