# Changing the command executed using suspend/standby in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management

I had some problems with my Thinkpad X200T not suspending under 14.04 LTS, after trying different solutions, it seems the easiest fix is to just execute

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

How would I go about making this the default action when suspending? (mapping System Menu -> Suspend and my FN+F4 button (the one with the moon icon :) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don' t know much about remapping keys, I suggest a workaround by binding `pm-suspend` to a keyboard shortcut. [Make pm-suspend executable without password](https://askubuntu.com/a/39294/295286) by placing something like 
`%yourusername ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend` into your `/etc/sudoers` file and then bind `gksu pm-suspend` to a shortcut in System Preferences -> keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom

Comment: Hm, this could be used as a workaround. So far I managed to get it to execute  'sudo pm-suspend' without asking for a password (  'gksu' was not installed, but even upon installing it it was still asking for a password). The problem now is that keyboard shortcuts do not seem to work. I tried System Preferences -> keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom, but that didn't work at all, so now I am attempting to use CompizConfig Settings Manager to set the shortcut, still no luck...

Comment: Interesting.  Running `gksu pm-suspend` in terminal never prompts me for a password (with pm-suspend already set to NOPASSWD in sudoers).  How about making the shortcut `/bin/sh -c "sudo pm-suspend"` ?

Comment: My apologies, it seems that my terminal simply cached the escelated privileges of the 'sudo visudo' command, while in fact 'sudo pm-suspend' still required authentication (it just didn't ask due to me typing in my password already for the visodo bit. Anyways, turns out that my sudoers file was somehow wrong (for anyone else that finds this, your NOPASSWD entries must be the last entries in the sudoers file I think). After correcting my sudoers file the '/bin/sh -c "sudo pm-suspend" '  comamnd magically worked, even as a keyboard shortcut from ccsm. Thank you very much!