# How to make Ubuntu to show a notification when there is a btrfs checksum failure?

Tags: btrfs, dmesg, notify-send, checksums

Like aa-notify, which shows a notification on my desktop when AppArmor denies something.

Comment: Data and/or metadata checksum failure. I am using a HDD which may be failing soon, got backups. As data and metadata get cheksumed on-the-fly with btrfs, I want to get alerted if there are bit-flips or any other hidden corruptions on my data. I've added this comment on the request of more info by @solsTiCe

Comment: I don't know which process is checking the corruptions, the kernel btrfs module itself?  I think it may report the failures in syslog. Trying to find it where now.

Comment: If we can trigger errors anywhere, the rest is easy.

Comment: According to [this](https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=116841) the errors are printed to dmesg.

Comment: Seems totally usable. only issue is that checking dmesg is very fast after clearing, (0.001 sec), but a bit longer after the computer runs for a long time without restart. Also clearing requires root privileges. Would clearing it from a background process bother you? The content can be stored in a file however until restart.

Comment: I don't know much about dmesg and about the concept of clearing dmesg. Do I have to clean it? And a new idea, maybe btrfs is also triggering something on checksum errors, It may be easier to act/display on the trigger.

Comment: Oh, now I understood you. It should work, but something that can alert on realtime would be better, as one can run 'btrfs scrub' -which checks the integrity- on cron also. Realtime would also help to find out which file has the corruption easily.

Comment: Yep, as in a few seconds.

Comment: @JacobVlijm The script is working nicely, it is even customizable for ufw firewall events, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the script below in the background will both show a notification:

[image]

...and add the error message with time stamp to the log file (`~/btrfs_errors.txt`), looking like:

```
Mon Oct 10 08:25:12 2016
BTRFS error (device md2): csum failed ino 7551 off 2310144 csum 623932426 expected csum 3810482428
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os

log = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], "btrfs_errors.txt")                                     

while True:
    msginfo = subprocess.check_output(["dmesg", "--read-clear"]).decode("utf-8")
    match = [l for l in msginfo.splitlines() if all(["btrfs" in l, "error" in l])]
    if match:
        with open(log, "a+") as out:
            out.write(time.ctime()+"\n")
            for l in match:
                out.write(l)
            out.write("\n\n")
        subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "-i", "gnome-disks",
                 "BTRFS error","Please see ~/btrfs_errors.txt for details"])

    time.sleep(4)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `check_btrfs`. ***Copy the script into a location where it cannot be edited without administrator's privileges***, such as `/usr/local/bin`. Make the script executable(!).
2. Add the script to the `sudoers` file, as described e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password). This is necessary, because the script is run by using `sudo`. The script reads from `dmesg`, and clears `dmesg`' history after reading, to prevent accumulating the amount of output to read. Clearing `dmesg` needs sudo privileges.
   This means however that *if* you need the output of `dmesg` for other purposes also, we need to work around. If so please mention.
3. Test- run it with the command:

   ```
   sudo check_btrfs
   ```

   if you copied it into a directory in `$PATH`. If not, include the path to the script.
4. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   sudo check_btrfs
   ```

Since I cannot test it with "real" `btrfs` errors, I ran it with checking for other events (pluging in a usb stick). In final the script, I used the message format in your link. The script checks on lines, containing both strings `btrfs` and `error`.

#### WHat it does

The script:

- once per four seconds reads the output of `dmesg`
- in case of an error, it shows a notification and adds the error to the file: `~/btrfs_errors.txt`
- clears the history of `dmesg` to keep the script "low on juice".

Comment: Thank you! It is just what I need, what btrfs users need. Something like this would be nice in ubuntu repos.
I don't know if I am using dmesg output, but I think one can still access it via journalctl. I could see the logs after I've ran dmesg --clear.

Comment: Just to trying to improve, as the script may be a base for a bigger script. I think the notification may also be achived without clearing dmesg; as dmesg logs are timestampted, the script may remember where did it read the last and continue from there.`[25436.495200] [UFW BLOCK] new line
[25436.495237] [UFW BLOCK]`

Comment: Hi @Artyom The stamps do not prevent the whole data cluster to be read. If you need it however, we can easily write it to a file, to be cleared on startup of the script. I did find a command to read/clear in one step though (how could I overlook that in `man dmesg`?). Will edit tomorrow or late today.