# Toggle caps lock LED on ThinkPad T43 - Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server, laptop, indicator, thinkpad, capslock

I have installed the above mentioned OS on a 15-year old IBM Thinkbad (t-43 / 1871 series).

I only care about the CAPS lock LED. Don't care about the others. Have reviewed some basic topics regarding *setleds* or similar but nowhere have I seen or understood exactly how to enable **toggle**. I have seen commands on how to manually turn the light on or off at will. That's silly, why should I have to do that. I want it to work the way it's supposed to: toggle on/off so that I know when I'm in caps on or caps off mode.

Can anyone suggest what amendments I need to make so that I can enable it? I would prefer solutions that don't require downloading extra software (remember this is a text-only interface that I have) as I want to keep the system light. I could do with some light scripting I suppose, but I'm really hoping there is a line somewhere in a system file that I need to amend to make this work. Otherwise open to some more involved solutions I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Please test the LED with this command: `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/input45\:\:capslock/brightness` to see if that works. If it does, there's an answer for you at https://askubuntu.com/a/851093/197910 . As to your bonus question, please click [edit] and remove it, and make that a new question; house rules are, one issue per question, so the site becomes a giant FAQ.

Comment: Yes it works when I set it on off manually like that. Incidentally I have input::3 if that matters. Anyway thanks for the link. It seems a bit too much for something I will not need all that much now that I think about it. I feel a bit nervous running a script that executes every second to make the caps key led work. I don’t fully understand it yet so will reconsider.

Comment: Well, I would slow it down to run every 5 secs if I was bothered by every second measurements, but there are so many other things going on in Linux I doublt this would be a problem even with a T43; and I have a lot of old slow Thunk Pads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No caps lock indicator light?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850997/no-caps-lock-indicator-light)