# Ubuntu 16.04 - How to start xampp control panel

Tags: xampp

How can I start xampp? After the installation there was no shortcut created on the desctop, now I am unable to find it. I am using the latest XAMPP for Linux 5.6.30, 7.0.15 & 7.1.1

The panel started right after the installation, but I am unable to find out how to start the panel after I closed it.

I read in some other topic to execute this command:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel
```

But this fails with:

```
 sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xampp-control-panel.py", line 18, in <module>
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

I also tried to search for xampp, but nothing relevant found:

[image]

UPDATE:

/opt/lampp

[image]

UPDATE:

I also tried to start xampp from the terminal like this:

root@ubuntu:/opt/lampp$ ./xampp panel

But then the xampp help page shows in the terminal and no GUI is starting:

[image]

Comment: try to install the python gtk package and then restart your xampp control panel ->                                  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/pygtk_2.24.0.orig.tar.gz

Comment: wow, already 10k views on something simple like this, ubuntu really needs to improve so it is easier to use, otherwise everyone will stay at windows

Comment: lol, 2019 and we have 227.000 Views, is it still that complicated?!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First of all you need to install gksu with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Then, run:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop
```

and save the following code in the file.

(You are using 64 bit system so there is no need to change anything, simply do copy paste)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Exec=gksudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=Application
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Note: For 32 bit xampp type "manager-linux.run" at place of "manager-linux-x64.run"

Run following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now check applications, its icon has been created.

It will not create icon on desktop, it will create a entry in applications search as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I have checked your directory it is correct, but some folders of xampp are missing. Check mine and compare.

[image]

---

To uninstall your current xampp

---

Copy paste below commands in terminal and hit enter button.

```
sudo -i
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./uninstall
```

---

To install XAMPP

---

```
Search `xampp-linux-x64-5.6.30-0-installer.run` in Google and download it. Then run:

chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.30-0-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.30-0-installer.run
```

---

Check if the following command runs or not:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

also check in this way if it works or not:

[image]

Comment: It will not create icon directly on desktop. Search as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: upload screenshot of directory /opt/lampp. (Go to this directory press print screen button and then  save it then upload it)

Comment: There are some folders which are missing in this directory. Did you launch xampp-control panel one time ?

Comment: I don't know, If it was launched successfully then why those folders are missing.  I have added all required code to run  xampp with icon.  Try with patience after reinstalling it.

Comment: I just uninstalled it and reinstalled it but have the same amount of folders and files as before.

Comment: Executing `sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run` worked. The GUI finally shows and I can start working finally... thx

Comment: did you get success in running shortcut or not ?

Comment: The shortcut is not working by far.

Comment: Wow, are XAMPP developers even testing their own software?

Comment: I got this solution to work with a slight adjustment. I swapped line...
`Exec=gksudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run`
with...
`Exec=gksudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel`

Comment: gksu is deprecated. It is removed from Debian, Ubuntu 18.04 and other newer Linux distribution version. The solution now is to use: https://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password

Comment: `Package 'gksu' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Package gksu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: my temp solution for `gksu` issue is just `sudo` instead of `gksu` in desktop entry like `Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run` downside is it requires the password every time if still can't see or run then just add the `Terminal=true`

Answer (score 68):

You can use one of the commands below.

- If you use a 32-bit system:

  ```
  sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux.run
  ```
- If you use a 64-bit system:

  ```
  sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
  ```

Comment: Works! And works well. Ideally Xampp should've created the necessary startup executables instead of expecting us to do it.

Comment: Damm right @Nav. They are trying to make us a complete nerd. and waste our time searching for this piece of ....

Comment: It works but when you close terminal control panel closes as well

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Short, simple and concise.

Comment: On linux mint to avoid typing that command again and again, you can do this: 
1) create launcher 
2) type that command in command box 
3) check the **run in terminal** option.
Now you can run that command on click, this time you just need to enter password.

Answer (score 6):

**In this post I explained how shortcuts actually works**

Firstly `gksu` should be installed in Ubuntu. Run the following command to confirm if it is installed, and it will install it if it isn't already:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Do the same as seen in the screenshots. 
All the shortcuts are present in applications folder. So you have to create file of shortcut in its directory. (do not forget to save)

Put the following text in `/usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Exec=gksudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=Application
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Now go to `/usr/share/applications` and check if the entry is created or not:

[image]

The extension of shortcut or icons is `.desktop`.

---

If there is already of shortcut of XAMPP present in this folder then you can also edit its code instead of creating new file, by knowing its name as shown below:

[image]

Now suppose that you want to edit code of `sol.desktop` run the following command:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sol.desktop
```

run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: gksu is deprecated. It is removed from Debian, Ubuntu 18.04 and other newer Linux distribution version. The solution now is to use: https://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps:

1. Install gnome-panel to be able to create launcher:

   `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel`
2. Run the below command to execute the Create Launcher Application:

   `gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Programs/Launchers --create-new`
3. The "create launcher" window pops up and select “Application” as the Type.
4. Enter for example “XAMPP starter” as the Name.
5. Enter “sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start” into the Command Box.
6. Press ok.

Comment: Thank you, but I get `gnome-desktop-item-edit: file:///root/Programs/Launchers does not have a .desktop or .directory suffix
`

Comment: This path [~/Programs/Launchers] is example! Create a folder and enter its path. The .desktop file will be saved there.

Comment: Ok I tried this, now there is a shortcut on my desctop, but nothing happens If I click on it.

Comment: Try this  "gnome-desktop-item-edit /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run --create-new" then run "sudo apt-get update" in terminal it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Find the installation directory of the XAMPP. Usually, it will be installed in the directory

```
/opt/lampp
```

change directory to /opt/lampp

```
cd /opt/lampp
```

To start XAMPP control panel

```
./manager-linux-x64.run
```

Use sudo if it says "Permission Denied" while executing the previous command.

```
sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
```

After executing the last command, the XAMPP control panel should open like this

[image]

Comment: `sudo manager-linux-x64.run` gives me `command not found error` but `sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run` doesn't .

Why ? 

Answer (score 2):

Your missing a module that `python` requires, `gtk`.
GTK is used to draw the GUI.

This command might do the trick:

```
sudo apt install python-gtk2
```

When it's done try to launch it again with:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel
```

Comment: I don't think that this is missing. If it was really missing, then how could the panel even show up right after the installation? Anyways, I get `Error importing pygtk2 and pygtk2-libglade`

Comment: You don't specify that the panel showed up "right after the installation". And I'm going of the python error message, that is either saying that you're missing python-gtk completely or it's not in python search path.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: Do you still need help with it, or did  you find your solution?

Comment: No thanks, It works now. I was able to open the pannel by executing `sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run` in the xampp folder

Answer (score 2):

As @Alamjit Singh already gave a really good and well explained answer, here it is a short summary on how to add an entry to the Desktop (app) + how to download and install XAMPP!

Run the following commands to install and run it:

```bsh
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/8.0.3/xampp-linux-x64-8.0.3-0-installer.run
$ chmod +x xampp-linux-*-installer.run
$ sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```

(follow the installation steps to finish it; you may close it after that)

Create a desktop icon for it:

```bsh
$ sudo touch /usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop
$ sudo vim /usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop
```

Paste this inside of the file, save it, and close it:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=Application
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Finally run `sudo apt-get update` and after that you should see a desktop icon like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create a launcher on the Desktop:

1) You need gksu so if you don't have it yet, run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

2) Run gedit (or any other text editor) and then enter the info below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Name[en_US]=XAMPP
Exec=gksu /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Comment[en_US]=Start XAMPP Control Panel
Name=XAMPP
Comment=Start XAMPP Control Panel
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Save the file on your Desktop as Xampp.desktop
```

3) Once the shortcut is on the Desktop, right-click on it, go to Properties, Permissions tab, and check "Allow executing file as program".

The above creates a shortcut for XAMPP Control Panel.

In case you want to run from your terminal type:

`sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run`

Answer (score -1):

You can make a shell script also.

Open `vim` editor

```
vim Xampp.sh
```

Then go to insert mode by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> and enter the following code

```
#Shell Script For Launching Xampp Control Panel
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
cd
```

If you are running a 32-bit version then copy the following code:

```
#Shell Script For Launching Xampp Control Panel
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./manager-linux.run
cd
```

Save the code by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> and writing:

```
:wq
```

This will save the code and exit the `vim` editor.

Change permissions of the shell script by issuing the following command:

```
chmod 775 Xammp.sh
```

Now you're done.

Simply run the shell script by using the following command:

```
./Xampp.sh
```

Comment: I don't think the question is about how to make a Shortcut or Script to open Xampp but rather facing a problem running Xampp in general.