# How to correctly insert sudo password in sudo command?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

I want to log in to user2 via bash script, so my script contains:

```
sudo -i -u user2
```

Also I don't want to enter my sudo password by hands. Before I did something like this:

```
echo "my_sudo_password" | sudo -S <command>
```

but if I am trying it in this case:

```
echo "my_sudo_password" | sudo -S -i -u user2
```

I have error

> -sh: 1: my_sudo_password: not found

Can you answer what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rather than hardcode the password somewhere, you can [add the script to sudoers](https://askubuntu.com/a/39294/1222991). This will allow *just* this script to run without the password requirement 

Comment: This is really not the intended way to use sudo and is not secure.   Hardcoding passwords is a very bad idea.  This doesn't work because sudo intentionally prevents it from working.

Comment: I *suspect* what's happening here is that your credentials are already cached, so `sudo` is not asking for your password, and the "unused" stdin is getting passed to user2's login shell (as if you'd done `echo "my_sudo_password" | sh -l`)

Comment: @matigo I have a Go CLI tool. When user run this tool it runs some bash commands. If I add that bash commands in sudoers, user will be able to use it manually, but I don't want that. What I need to do in this situation? For now, the only option that I've invented is hardcode the sudo password and run sudo without caching any creds :(

Answer (score 0):

If lack of security doesn't bother you, you can try this:

```
coproc ( sleep 2; xdotool key your_password key Return )
sudo -i -u user2
```

which simulates your doing it by hand. The sleep wait time can be adjusted to suit your situation.